# Reconnect to server using offline files

Tags: windows-7, offline-files

Some users are seeing grey boxes on folder icons. This indicates that they are viewing the offline folders.

How do I determine...

1. Did it go offline due to a slow link?
2. Is it trying to reconnect automatically?

How can I force it to check again for server availability?

Server 2008r2 standard
client: win7 pro.

Answer (score 2):

I have given a similar answer [elsewhere](https://superuser.com/questions/973979/troubleshooting-windows-offline-files-status-offline-no-connection/987696#987696), but I do believe it is suitable here too.

Create the new registry DWORD32 value `SilentForcedAutoReconnect` set to `1`, inside registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\NetCache\
```

It forces the synchronised folders back online automatically once the network is available again.

Optionally, you can also disable the slow-link detection in Group Policy at:

- Local Computer Policy --> Computer Configuration --> Administrative Templates --> Network --> Offline Files

set `Configure slow-link mode` to `Disabled`

Answer (score 0):

You can sent conditions and settings for offline files form windows 7 by going to sync center. Open Sync Center by clicking the Start button, clicking All Programs, clicking Accessories, and then clicking Sync Center. This will allow you to turn on or off going offline for a slow link and also determine when it will go online and resync.